# How to trigger a refresh when coming back to a fragment from another app in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my fragment, I am setting variable in onSaveInstanceState() but when I come back to the app after going to a different app or homescreen there is no callback for me to retrieve the savedInstanceState. onCreateView(), onViewStateRestored() or any other of the callbacks that have access to savedInstanceState are not called. How am I supposed to this?

Comment: Have you tried onResume() or onStart()?

Comment: you will get variable from *onActivityCreated* `s bundle.

Comment: @adnbsr onActivityCreated isn't called I think because the app is still running in background at this point.

Comment: @JudeFernandes they don't have access to savedInstanceState

Comment: Since the fragment is not being destroyed the data should still persist when you come back so you should be able to refer to the variable directly?Store them as global variables for that fragment.